# How to get values of disabled dropdownFor in mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a dropdownListFor controls which are cascade in nature on edit i do need to disabled the below cascaded dropdown lists until the values get changed from the first one , so below is my code of dropdown list

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Program_Id, "Program_Id", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">

            @Html.DropDownList("Program_Id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ddlPrograms" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Program_Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am making them disable using javascript

```
   document.getElementById("ddlYear").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("ddlBlocks").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("ddlModules").disabled = true;
```

But on Edit when I submit the forms instead of selected value they send 0 to the controller . how to fix that issue if i am using hidden field then how i would be able to access this hidden field value as i am using entity framework and below is my controller edit post method

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "Course_Id,Course_Name,Course_Code,Course_Visibility,Course_Start_Date,Course_End_Date,Block_Id,Module_Id,Program_Id,Year,Course_Description,Course_Image,Course_Category_Id,Course_Content_File_Path,Course_announcement,Course_Tags,Status,Course_Short_Name,Date_Created,Date_Modified")] Courses courses)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(courses).State = EntityState.Modified;
                if (db.SaveChanges() > 0)
                {
                    TempData["UpdatedMessage"] = "Updated Successfully";
                }
               // await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.Block_Id = new SelectList(db.Blocks, "Id", "Name", courses.Block_Id);
            ViewBag.Course_Category_Id = new SelectList(db.Courses_Category, "Id", "Category_Name", courses.Course_Category_Id);
            ViewBag.Module_Id = new SelectList(db.Moduels, "Id", "Name", courses.Module_Id);
            ViewBag.Program_Id = new SelectList(db.Programs, "Id", "Program_Title", courses.Program_Id);
            ViewBag.Year = new SelectList(db.Years, "Id", "Name", courses.Year);
            return View(courses);
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `disabled` form items are not submitted to the server. This is true in any HTML form, it's not MVC-related. The solution is not to disable them. Logically, if it's disabled, then the user should not be able to select it, so how could they submit it? Rather than disabling the cascaded dropdowns, simply empty them out before the user has selected something from the earlier one. Then re-populate them when the parent dropdown changes its value. It's unclear why you'd ever need to disable them.

Comment: – ADyson Thanks for the reply , let me share the need to disable them basically let see if i have three dropdown like country state and city ,country populate state and state populate cities , Now my adding new record is working fine with cascade nature , but on editing i need to show their selected value rather than making them empty (as you are saying make them empty ) if i make them empty on edit how the user would knew their previous value so I need to show the previous value , But right now they are populated with all values rather then the cascaded values

Comment: "if i make them empty on edit how the user would knew their previous value so I need to show the previous value"...I didn't say to do that though. I said to make them empty when the user has not selected any value in the parent dropdown. Sorry if that was not clear. And if they do select something, then populate the child dropdown with all the allowed options under that category. If they if they select "USA" as country then at that moment you can populate the "State" box with all U.S. states. When they select "California" state you then populate all cities in California.

Comment: "right now they are populated with all values rather then the cascaded values"...so then you need to fix that so the dropdowns are only populated with relevant values to begin with.

Comment: You can have an hidden field that holds the value of the disabled field and send that with the form instead. Also, have you tried making the field `readonly`. I am not sure how that will behave with dropdowns but works well with text box.